# R Shiny dynamic slider animation

Tags: r, shiny

This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522812/r-shiny-animated-slider-with-renderui) but since there is no answer I thought I'd post another simple example in the hopes of finding an answer.

The problem is that the animation option for sliderInput() does not work when the slider is built dynamically using renderUI().

So while this works fine:

```
# works 
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

    sliderInput("animationSlider", "non-dynamic animation slider", 
                min = 1, max = 100, value = 1, step = 1,
                animate = animationOptions(200)),

    textOutput("sliderValue")

  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$sliderValue <- renderText(paste("value:", input$animationSlider))

  }
)
```

This doesn't work:

```
#doesn't work
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

    numericInput("max", "Set max value for dynamic animation slider", 
                value = 10),
    uiOutput("animationSlider"),
    textOutput("sliderValue")

  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$animationSlider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("animationSlider", "Dynamic animation slider", 
                  min = 1, max = input$max, value = 1, step = 1,
                  animate = animationOptions(200))
    })

    output$sliderValue <- renderText(paste("value:", input$animationSlider))

  }
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is working fine, you just cannot have 2 divs with the same name:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

    numericInput("max", "Set max value for dynamic animation slider", 
                 value = 10),
    uiOutput("animationSlider"),
    textOutput("sliderValue")

  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$animationSlider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("animationSlider2", "Dynamic animation slider", 
                  min = 1, max = input$max, value = 1, step = 1,
                  animate = animationOptions(200))
    })

    output$sliderValue <- renderText(paste("value:", input$animationSlider2))

  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solution works and now the value of the slider can be accessed by input$animationSlider2.